# Querying if Office 365 is installed on button event, then executing code based on return value (WPF/C# app)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, office365

Background: I'm creating an app that allows our other techs to quickly install a dozen or so programs within one simple GUI. I am embedding the installers of those apps within my main program. (not that it matters)

I created a separate class file (`IsOfficeInstalled.cs`) that gets called when a user clicks on a button to install Office. Here's the code in that file:

```
 class IsOfficeInstalled
    {
        public static bool check()
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe");
            if (key != null)
            {
                key.Close();
            }
            return key != null; }}
```

In my `MainWindow.xaml` file, I am trying to call the "IsOfficeInstalled" function and perform one of two actions based on the return value. This is where I am confused. The code in my button event looks like the following:

```
 private void btn_InstallOffice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    if (IsOfficeInstalled.check())
    {
        //If yes, then perform some code
    }
    else
    {
       //If no, then perform some different code
    }
```

Where I need help is, getting the true/false result back from the "IsOfficeInstalled" function so my code in the "btn_InstallOffice_Click" function will know which condition to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question. Are you looking for a simple if statement?

```
private void btn_InstallOffice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (IsOfficeInstalled.check())
    {
        //If yes, then perform some code
    }
    else
    {
       //If no, then perform some different code
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get/pass the return value from the first function so the button event will know what code to execute based on true or false.

Comment: It looks like you are already doing that in your return statement. if the key is null false is returned. If you want to store the result in a variable for future use just assign it like this: `bool isInstalled = IsOfficeInstalled.check();`